# Is Property in any way reserved for rails model naming? (Rails pluralisation is killing me.)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am trying to add a model called Properties in Rails 3.1 So I used created it using ryan bates nifty generator, although the model itself is very basic for now and only includes.

```
class Property < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

in my resources I have"

```
resources :properties
```

In one of my views I am simply trying to do the following:

```
<% for property in Property.all %>
 <p>description etc</p>
<% end %>
```

but it gives me the following error?!

```
undefined method `all' for Property:Module
```

Now it works if I replace Property.all with User.all or House.all but for some reason Property doesn't work. I'm kinda new to rails and think it has something to do with pluralization but I can't figure it out and its killing me. If anyone could please help that would be epic! Cheers

Comment: `Property` is not a reserved word in Rails as far as I know. What other gems are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **Inflections** to extend default dictionary ( peoperty word is not included by default). The official [API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector/Inflections.html) can help you with it

Answer (score 0):

In your model definition you need to tell it the real name of your table, eg.

```
class Property < ActiveRecord::Base
    set_table_name "properties"
end
```

Also you may want to adapt the code slightly for showing your data, it's better to use your controller to grab the data, and the view to display it

In your controller

```
def index
  @properties = Property.all
end
```

In your view

```
<% @properties.each do |property| %>
  <%= property.description %>  
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks, your suggestions made a lot of sense unfortunately they have not made the error go away. If you have any other ideas I would love to hear more. Thanks again.

Comment: Hmmm.  Is your model filename for property named 'property'?  Also does it fail when you add @properties = Property.all into your controller index method?

Comment: Yes to both. It seems very strange right. I created an identical model using the very same terminal command only this time I called the model House instead of Property and it works fine?

Comment: Very strange indeed.  Could you post your model, view and controller code as you have it now.